# JQuery не работает с подгруженными с помощью AJAX элементами

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, html, css

Вот, допустим, простой код:

```
$('[data-modal]').on('click', function() {
// Если есть на странице модальное окно - открываем его
    if( $($(this).attr('data-modal')).length ) {
        show_modal( $(this).attr('data-modal') );
    } else {
// Если нету - загружаем по AJAX и открываем
        var data_modal_rpl = $(this).attr('data-modal').replace('#', '');
        $('body').load('/ajax/load/'+data_modal_rpl+'.php');
        show_modal( $(this).attr('data-modal') );
    }
    return false;
});
// А тут мы уже закрываем модальное окошко при нажатии на определенные кнопки.
$('.modal_close, .modal_close_bg').on('click', function() {
    hide_modal();
    return false;
});
```

Вот собственно проблема в том, что, в данном случае, код по закрытию окошек обрабатывает только те кнопки, которые уже есть на странице. А те, что подгружены по AJAX - нет.

Это можно как-то исправить?

Все это дело в `$(document).ready();`

Comment: Можете объяснить что это значит `$('[data-modal]')`, мне просто интересно, это у вас элемент такой?

Comment: @Maris - это любые элементы с атрибутом [data-modal]. Как правило у меня это <a href="#" data-modal="#modal_id">Открыть окно</a>

Comment: Спасибо за `notice`!

Comment: просто в в HTML код ваш вставте сразу обработчик onclick="" ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Я первый раз, когда наткнулся на эту проблему, тоже долго думал, почему не хочет клик обрабатывать. А потом доперло, что событие то было навешано до того, как появились новые элементы!

Тогда еще существовал метод [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/), который уже `deprecated`.

Вместо него теперь метод [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), но конструкция чуть сложнее выглядит. Объясню на примере:

Допустим у нас есть документ со структурой:

```
<div class='container'>
   <a href='page'>link</a>
</div>
```

В который мы будем добавлять новые элементы (не важно как мы их добавляем):

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('.container').append("<a href='page'>link</a>");
});
```

Собственно остался вопрос: как правильно повесить событие, чтобы и на уже имеющиеся элементы стояло событие, и на новые добавлялось?

Обратимся в документацию по методу `on()`, и видим такую вещь:

```
$('.container').on('click', 'a', function(){
...
});
```

Т.е. что произошло: мы задали во втором параметре тот селектор, на который хотим добавить событие. А в функции `$()` указываем, где будет происходить "поиск" селектора, который указан во втором параметре.

Comment: Дело проясняется. Спасибо! А как быть тогда с функциями? Вот я окошко то загрузил.. А теперь мне нужно его показать с помощью ф-ии show_modal('#loaded_modal'); Грубо говоря - это тот же fadeIn()

Comment: @lampa.. Хотя может я не то спрашиваю. Но первую строку я заменил на это: $('body').on('click', '[data-modal]', function() {... Но вот не работает как то :(

Comment: @inferus-vv конструкция добавления события ничем не отличается от вашей: гляньте лучше пример, он должен быть наглядней: http://jsfiddle.net/S4h2q/

Answer (score 3):

Кстати, очень короткий пример, как может работать `on`.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="test">Test</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#wrapper').on('click','p',function(){

    alert('Ok!');

});

$('#test').append('<p>New Paragraph</p>');
```

**css:**

```
p { cursor: pointer; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// А тут мы уже закрываем модальное окошко при нажатии на определенные кнопки.
$(document).on('click','.modal_close, .modal_close_bg', function() {
    hide_modal();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: неа, не работает

Comment: А, вы просто 1-ее ответили, ну ничего.

Comment: Должно работать. Можете также попробовать .delegate()
http://api.jquery.com/delegate/